# accepts_nested_attributes_for and select tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I've a Room model and a Person model.

A room can have many person and a person can have one room.

On the room creation screen I can 'link' n person to this new room
So i want to have a variable amount of select tag which contains the list of all people

I don't know how to build the select tag.

Can anyone help

thanks...

I've the following associations

```
class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :people
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :people
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :room
end
```

I use a partial to build the rooms/new form

```
<% form_for(@room) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :date %><br />
    <%= f.date_select :date %>
  </p>
  <% f.fields_for :people do |builder| %>
    <p>
      <%= builder.label :person_id, "Person" %><br />
      <%= select 'room', 'people', Person.all.collect{|person| [person.name, person.id]}%>
    </p>
  <% end %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :comment %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :comment %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit 'Create' %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice... and quick answer thanks!

here is the tested code to be correct

```
  <% f.fields_for :people do |builder| %>
    <p>
      <%= builder.label :person_id, "Person" %><br />
      <%= builder.collection_select :person_id, Person.all, :id, :name, {:multiple => true} %>
    </p>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [ActionView::Helpers::FormOptionsHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html) module. It supplies the collection_select method.

This partial does what you're looking for:

```
<% form_for(@room) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :date %><br />
    <%= f.date_select :date %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :people_ids, "Person" %><br />
    <%= collection_select :people_ids, Person.all, :name, :id, {:multiple => true} %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :comment %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :comment %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit 'Create' %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```